# Color input's border when nothing is entered doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input text that has to be something in it for the form to work.

So I wish to add some functionality to the `Confirm` button that checks if the input field is empty, and if so, recolor the border of that input.

I'm doing the following:

```js
$(function mainListeners () {   
    "use strict";
    
    var confirm = $('#addNewConfirm');
    var cancel = $('#addNewCancel');
    var eventBox = $('#eventname_input');
console.log("RUNS!!");
    confirm.onclick = function (e) {
        if (eventBox.val() == ''){
            //so if we have an empty event
            //recolor borders.
            console.log("CHANGES!!");
            eventBox.css('border-color','#d81919');
        }else {
            
        }
    }
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="yesno IFlexible">
     <button id="addNewConfirm" >Confirm</button>
     <button id="addNewCancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
<div >
    <label>Event:</label>
    <input id="eventname_input" type="text" />
</div>
```

Here I get no errors and I always see the `RUNS!!` message, so my script is attached. However, I never see the `CHANGES!!` message, so the condition `eventBox.val() == ''` is never true. I looked up the internet on how to check if an input text's text is empty, and this is what I found, and it clearly isn't working.

How can I sort out this recolor of border if the input has no text?

Comment: well what is `event`?

Comment: Renaming done wrong xd editing the stuff now, just a minute.

Comment: well jQuery does not have  `confirm.onclick`

Comment: Right, you can either use $(confirm).on('click') or add the attribute `onClick` to the element with `id=addNewConfirm`.

Also, you need to check for null values as well as `''` values.

Comment: lol someone marked this as 'off-topic, not related to programming' xd s/he must have been some hardcore assembly developer then

Comment: Yeah, I am so hardcore when you did not use a library right. :) I am too lazy to find a dupe where someone used onclick instead of `click(...)` or `on("click",  ..)`

Comment: true, but it doesn't make the question "not about programming" xd

Comment: No the actual close is typo which is under that category.

Comment: doesn't really matter, the issue is solved. wish jQ would slap on my hand like good ol' c# when used wrong :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JQuery [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) function instead of onclick like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var confirm = $("#addNewConfirm");
  var cancel = $("#addNewCancel");
  var eventBox = $("#eventname_input");
  console.log("RUNS!!");
  confirm.click(function(e) {
    if (!eventBox.val()) {
      console.log("CHANGES!!");
      eventBox.css("border-color", "#d81919");
    } else {
      eventBox.css("border-color", 'inherit');
      // whatever you want
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="yesno IFlexible">
  <button id="addNewConfirm">Confirm</button>
  <button id="addNewCancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Event:</label>
  <input id="eventname_input" type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using either the Jquery method of setting a click event (.click()) or the vanilla JS way of retrieving a DOM element(document.getElementById()).

Below is a working example of changes!! getting called.

```js
$(function mainListeners () {   
    "use strict";
    
    var confirm = document.getElementById('addNewConfirm'); //GET DOM ELEMENTS THIS WAY OR SEE BELOW FOR CLICK
    var cancel = $('#addNewCancel');
    var eventBox = $('#eventname_input');
console.log("RUNS!!");
    confirm.onclick = function (e) {//OR CHANGE THIS TO CLICK()
        if (eventBox.val() == ''){
            //so if we have an empty event
            //recolor borders.
            console.log("CHANGES!!");
            event.css('border-color','#d81919');
        }else {
            
        }
    }
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="yesno IFlexible">
     <button id="addNewConfirm" >Confirm</button>
     <button id="addNewCancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
<div >
    <label>Event:</label>
    <input id="eventname_input" type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that `onclick` is vanilla Javascript and you are trying to use it on the confirm jQuery object.

In order to fix it, you can use `confirm[0].click = function(e)` syntax or `confirm.click(function (e)`. I suggest you to use jQuery syntax: if you load this library you are encouraged to use it in order to strengthen readability.